# How can I take last 20 lines from the $BUILD_LOG variable?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

When using Email-ext plugin, I would like also to write the last 20 lines of the build log there (not attached as a file)
I know I can access the log using $BUILD_LOG variable, but don't know exactly how to take the las 20 lines from that variable.
Any help?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: How to do the same using groovy script which will then run on jenkins script console?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the following syntax, from the Content Token reference:

**${BUILD_LOG, maxLines, escapeHtml}** - Displays the end of the build log.
maxLines - display at most this many lines of the log.
Defaults to 250.
escapeHtml - If true, HTML is escaped.
Defaults to false.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used
${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=50, escapeHtml=false}
and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the last 20 lines of BUILD_LOG

```
${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=20, escapeHtml=false}
```

[jenkins Custom Message slack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4VHV.png)