# Jenkins: ${BUILD_LOG, maxLines, escapeHtml} not working

Tags: groovy, jenkins, continuous-integration, email-attachments

I am trying to use "${BUILD_LOG, maxLines, escapeHtml}" like discribed in:
[How can I take last 20 lines from the $BUILD_LOG variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089096/how-can-i-take-last-20-lines-from-the-build-log-variable)

Unfortunately it doesn't work for me.

I get this error:

> Script1.groovy: 114: expecting anything but ''\n''; got it anyway @ line 114, column 301.
>      arted by user MYUSERNAME

My code in this line is:

```
          msg.setText("This build (" + build.getFullDisplayName() 
          + " ) contains the following tasks:\n\nTASK\t\t\t  IMPLEMENTER:\n" 
          + taskList + "\n\n\nLink to this 
          build: ${BUILD_URL} \n ${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=9999, escapeHtml=false}" );
```

---

If I take this out the following, it works. Thats why my guess is, that "**BUILD_LOG**" is not working anymore?

> ${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=9999, escapeHtml=false}

---

EDIT:
Maybe as addition: I am trying to do this withing the PreSend groovy script.
Since I am building the Email text dynamically.
`${BUILD_URL}` works fine, `${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=9999, escapeHtml=false}` doesn't (for me) i am looking for a solution for this...
the `msg` object is a java MimeMessage.

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

That error message is usually related to not closed quotes, comments started with `/` instead of `//`, etc. In your code the only thing I can see is that your third line is not finished properly, i.e., after `"\n\n\nLink to this` you are not closing double quotes and instead you are starting a new line (thereby the `expecting anything but ''\n''`.

Try to write the whole line:

```
msg.setText("This build (" + build.getFullDisplayName() 
          + " ) contains the following tasks:\n\nTASK\t\t\t  IMPLEMENTER:\n" 
          + taskList + "\n\n\nLink to this build: ${BUILD_URL} \n ${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=9999, escapeHtml=false}" );
```

or close the quotes instead:

```
msg.setText("This build (" + build.getFullDisplayName() 
          + " ) contains the following tasks:\n\nTASK\t\t\t  IMPLEMENTER:\n" 
          + taskList + "\n\n\nLink to this "
          + "build: ${BUILD_URL} \n ${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=9999, escapeHtml=false}" );
```

Comment: thanks for your input. Actually I did this, to have it readable here. Right now it is all in one line. So the quote "+ taskList + "\n\n\nLink" goes until the end. Because I had the same thought (more or less), just tried to solve it differently...

Comment: Yes :( even with: ${BUILD_LOG} alone in the string.

Comment: Watch that the error says "column 301"... search for a quite long line in your script. I'm quite sure it has to do with not closed quotes... Putting the hole line together (even with white spaces) I only get 265 chars.

Comment: You are right, I never reach this length. But it doesn't eplain why without this it just works. No additional brackts or quotes. Have u tried this on your side?
I mean, I spent quite some time trying and searching the nets, before looking for my SO pw and ask here... :S

Answer (score 0):

I used the below and it's working fine for me.

```
${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=10, escapeHtml=false}
```

I tried with Jenkins version 1.617

Comment: This exactly what I wrote... ?! and It's not working for me with: Jenkins ver. 1.609.2 (LTS) see the example above... I tried also with less and without maxLines... no change

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set `escapeHtml=true`? It may happen that this token expanded as is and then string in `" "` becomes not valid.

Comment: Will give it a try :)

Comment: Unfortunately i doesn't work either. I always points to a colum which doesn't exist. and the "^" pointing to the error point to my username. I really had high hopes here. Also tried mail content as HTML and plain text... no change, as soon as "${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=9999, escapeHtml=true}" is within the string...
thanks though for giving it a thought...

Comment: Maybe try get build_log content into variable and escape new lines with .replace("\", "\\")? Then it shouldn't break string in `setText()`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I was busy with other stuff. This doesn't allow me to "embed" the log file as attachment just like this. If I use BUILD_LOG_REGEX, I don't get an error, but neither an attached log :(

Answer (score 0):

In latest version variable ${BUILD_LOG} wasn't available for me - only solution to get log in email content was for me setting:

```
msg.setText(build.getLog())
```

as Default Pre-send Script in Jenkins global configuration...