# Can't access $BUILD_LOG in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How do I access `$BUILD_LOG` in a Jenkins pipeline, or is there a better way of getting the log output?

Going off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16093267/5031373), I've been trying to access the `$BUILD_LOG` environment variable, but when I try

```
echo "${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=50, escapeHtml=false}"
```

the build errors out:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 11: unexpected token: BUILD_LOG @ line 11, column 29.
                       echo "${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=50, escapeHtml=false}"
```

And if I try

```
echo "$BUILD_LOG"
```

I get this error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: BUILD_LOG for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

What am I doing wrong?  Or is this the wrong way to access the printed output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the answer you linked the BUILD_LOG variable is set by the [email-extension plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin). Do you have this configured correctly as this may be your issue.

Comment: That was it. I was trying to use `${BUILD_LOG}` outside of the `emailext` step. Apparently this variable only works there.

Comment: I am trying to use the $BUILD_LOG inside the emailext plugin but it still doesnt work. Here is the gist -https://gist.github.com/vijayakumar-psg587/4e37efe4daf0cd8dbaf153da94e01fea

Comment: I end up with the following error - groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: BUILD_LOG for class: groovy.lang.Binding
 at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)

Comment: @Joey587, have you found any solution for this? I found just a workaround I've posted below in separate answer.

Comment: No @Vladimir. I will take a look at it. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with declarative pipelines and a step like:

```
emailext(
  subject: "foo",
  to: "bar",
  body: """<p>FAILED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]':</p>
  <p>Console output (last 250 lines):<hr><pre>${BUILD_LOG}</pre></p>"""
```

I had email ext plugin installed.

The solution was to escape the $-sign of the the macro that should be expanded by the plugin, like so:

```
...
<p>Console output (last 250 lines):<hr><pre>\${BUILD_LOG}</pre></p>"""
...
```

**And be sure to use double quotes.**

This way groovy (?) will first expand all the environment variables, and leaves the escaped variables to be dealt with by email ext plugin.

Comment: Escaping the $ worked for me.  I don't understand why it works though?

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli there are 2 different postprocess steps in play here (Jenkins itself, and emailext plugin), and unfortunately both use `$` to indicate a macro. `$BUILD_LOG` belongs to emailext, and if the `$`-sign is not escaped, Jenkins tries to replace it with a value. But Jenkins doesn't know this macro, so it replaces it with empty string (or something). When it is escaped with \-character, Jenkins just strips the \ from it, leaving the `$BUILD_LOG` macro to be handled by emailext plugin. So escaping delays the processing of the macro until correct stage.

Answer (score 4):

Still haven't found a solution to use BUILD_LOG parameter in a pipeline job with emailext plugin.

As a small solace, I found a workaround to access build log in another way:

```
currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(15)
```

Where 15 is a number of last log lines I want to show.

The example is:

```
  emailext attachLog: true,
                    body: "Build failed" +
                            "<br> See attached log or URL:<br>${env.BUILD_URL}" +
                            "<br><br> <b>The end of build log is:</b> <br>" +
                            currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(15).join("<br>"),

                    mimeType: 'text/html',
                    subject: "Build failed",
                    to: 'myemail@somedomain.com'
```

Note that you have to approve a few script signatures at the In-Process Script Approval in order to allow usage of this function.